# R: AR(1) model. How to estimate using OLS?

Tags: r, time-series

I am using log returns values for AR(1) model. I want to estimate the a and B in the equation:

```
r(t) = a + Br(t-1) + e #where e is error
```

I am using data from yahoo as follows:

```
library(tseries)
security<-"MMM"
startDate<-"2012-06-01"
endDate<-"2016-10-31"
qte_list<-c("AdjClose")

price=get.hist.quote(instrument = security, startDate, endDate, quote = qte_list,   provider = "yahoo" )
ret<-diff(log(price[,1]))
```

i then fitted the returns in an arima of order c(1,0,0) to make it AR(1)

```
fit<-arima(ret, order=c(1,0,0))
```

from here I get the residuals.

Now I want to find the a and B from above to be able to generate a new sample using the residuals above. So my question is, how do I estimate the a and B with OLS (ordinary Least squares) or Linear least squares?

Thank you

Comment: `library(zoo)` is missing from the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ar.ols(coredata(ret), order.max = 1, demean = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
Call:
ar.ols(x = coredata(ret), order.max = 1, demean = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)

Coefficients:
      1  
-0.0537  

Intercept: 0.0007582 (0.0002974) 

Order selected 1  sigma^2 estimated as  9.765e-05
```

Comment: thank you. When i run the `fit<-arima(ret, order=c(1,0,0))` i get 1611 residuals whereas my initial input data just has 1112 rows. May I know why is this? Also, how can i get a sample of the residuals with replacement?

Comment: It's expanding the input to add NAs for the weekends since it requires regularly spaced input.    Try `arima(coredata(ret), c(1, 0, 0))` .